# Antipodal map as $\;1,2\;$ or $\;3\;$ reflections?

Tags: geometry

This is a homework question which asks to write the antipodal map as the composition of one, two or three reflections ?

I understand what antipode is, but I am lost on where to begin on this question.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If you’re working in the plane, what happens when you reflect a point in the $y$-axis and then reflect the result in the $x$-axis? Where does it end up relative to the coordinate origin?

**Added:** In $\Bbb R^3$, notice that if you reflect in the coordinate plane perpendicular to the $x$-axis, you change the sign of the $x$-coordinate but leave the other two coordinates alone. A similar thing happens with each of the coordinate axes. The point antipodal to $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ is $\langle -x,-y,-z\rangle$, so ... ?

Comment: Would that be the same as reflecting in the origin ?

Comment: @devcoder: Yes, it would.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure how that relates to the question though

Comment: @devcoder: If $p$ is a point on the unit circle centred at the origin, its antipodal point is the point diametrically opposite; where is that in relation to the origin?

Comment: On the same unit circle, on the opposite side same distance as p is from the origin

Comment: @devcoder: In other words, it’s the reflection of $p$ through the origin. So the antipodal map can be obtained by composing what reflections?

Comment: I see the reflection part. So I can see antipodal map having one reflection which is the point and it's antipodal point, right ? but overall I guess what is confusing me is that what exactly does "composing reflections" mean ?

Comment: @devcoder: A reflection of $\Bbb R^n$ (here $\Bbb R^2$) is just a function from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^n$. Composing two reflections is just composing those functions: do one, then do the other to the output of the first $-$ exactly what I described in the hint.

Comment: So that means, if we start with a point on the sphere, 1 reflection gives the anitpodal point, 2 relfections gives the same starting point, 3 reflections again the antipodal point ?

Comment: @devcoder: Let’s stick with the plane, because I don’t think that you’ve quite got that. Although I called it *reflection through the origin*, the antipodal map is not itself a reflection: in the plane *reflection* means *reflection in a line*. Thus, the antipodal map is the composition of two reflections: reflection in the $y$-axis, followed by reflection in the $x$-axis. In $\Bbb R^3$ *reflection* means *reflection in a plane*. Can you compose three reflections in planes to get the antipodal map on the sphere?

Comment: I get the two reflections for the antipodal map part, but can't figure out how I'd use three reflections to get the same

Comment: @devcoder: Hang on a minute, and I’ll add a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Oh I think I get it. So the three reflections are needed in planes perpendicular to x, y, z to give me the antipodal point ?

Comment: @devcoder: They do indeed. And in one dimension *reflection* means reflection in a point, and a single reflection in the origin gives you the antipodal map.

Comment: So is the question asking me to find the antipodal map in one, two and three dimensions ?

Comment: @devcoder: It might be; or, if a specific dimensional context has previously been established, it might simply be telling you that the right number is one of one, two, and three and leaving you to figure out which.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to put this in best to my understanding. I highly appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: @devcoder: You’re welcome!